# How to update an array element in a MongoDB document

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

I've got a problem updating an array element in MongoDB. This is the structure of a document:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57e2645e11c979157400046e"),
        "site" : "BLABLA",
        "timestamp_hour" : 1473343200,
        "values" : [
                {
                        "1473343200" : 66
                },
                {
                        "1473344100" : 230
                },
                {
                        "1473345000" : 479
                },
                {
                        "1473345900" : 139
                }
        ]
}
```

Now I want to update the element with key "1473345900". How can I do this? I've tried:

```
db.COLLECTIONNAME.update({"values.1473345900": {$exists:true}}, {$set: {"values.$": 0}})
```

But after that the document looks like:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57e2645e11c979157400046e"),
        "site" : "BLABLA",
        "timestamp_hour" : 1473343200,
        "values" : [
                {
                        "1473343200" : 66
                },
                {
                        "1473344100" : 230
                },
                {
                        "1473345000" : 479
                },
                0
        ]
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? I only want to update the value of 1473345900 to any value... I don't want to update the complete element...

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an additional query in your update that matches the array element you want to update. A typical query would involve checking for the element's value not equal to the one being updated.

The following example update shows this where the **`$`** positional operator identifies the correct index position of the hash key array element `{ "1473345900": 139 }`. If you try to run the update operation without the **`$`** positional operator:

```
db.COLLECTIONNAME.update(
    { "values.1473345900": { "$exists": true } }, 
    { "$set": { "values.1473345900": 0 } }
)
```

mongo will treat the timestamp 1473345900 as the index position and thus you will get the error

> can't backfill array to larger than 1500000 elements

Thus the correct way should be:

```
var val = 32;   
db.COLLECTIONNAME.update(
    { "values.1473345900": { "$ne": val, "$exists": true } },
    { "$set": { "values.$.1473345900": val } }
)
```

Comment: The problem is: I don't know if **1473345900** already exists. So 1) I have to find out if **1473345900** exists and 2) I have to update the value of **1473345900**. Sorry, I missed to explain that...

Comment: `db.sites.update({"values.1473345900": {$exists:true}}, {$set: {"values.$.1473345900": 0}})` will work do it. Thx, Chridam!!!